# Form validation with dates. First date must be earlier than second date input

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have been trying to find a solution for days now.  I am not strong in javascript and it confuses me.
I want the submit button disabled unless the start time is earlier that the end time. I can do this so easily in PHP but I need to prevent submission of a form on the client side in this case.  I was able to figure out basic numbers but not date-times.  I also would like to insert a message inside of the div tags with the id of message.

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="start" id="start">
<input type="datetime-local" name="end" id="end">
<div id="message"></div>

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Click to Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="start" id="start">
<input type="datetime-local" name="end" id="end">
<div id="message"></div>

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Click to Submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let startInput = document.getElementById('start');
  let endInput = document.getElementById('end');
  let messageDiv = document.getElementById('message');
  let submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

  let compare = () => {
    let startValue = (new Date(startInput.value)).getTime();
    let endValue = (new Date(endInput.value)).getTime();

    if (endValue < startValue) {
      messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Start date must be before end date!';
      submitButton.disabled = true;
    } else {
      messageDiv.innerHTML = '';
      submitButton.disabled = false;
    }
  };

  startInput.addEventListener('change', compare);
  endInput.addEventListener('change', compare);
</script>
```

First, we store all the HTML elements we need in variables. Then we declare a function that we run whenever either date input changes. Inside that function, we check if the end date is before the start date. If it is, we display the error message and disable the submit button; if it isn't, we hide the error message and enable the submit button.

I ran this code and it works.

Comment on this answer if you have questions.

Comment: Wow, that's works really well.  I'm really struggling to understand the logic on the following line:

let compare = () => {

The way you handled the date values looks easier than my research was leading me.

Comment: Is the () the same as OR?, it reads equal to OR equal to/greater than?

Comment: `() => {...}` is (roughly) the same as writing `function () {...}`. Both declare a function that takes zero arguments. So, all I'm doing in that line is declare a function and then assign it to the `compare` variable.

Comment: See more on arrow functions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="datetime-local" name="start" >
  <input type="datetime-local" name="end"  >
  <div id="message"></div>

  <button type="submit" name="btSubmit" disabled>Click to Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')

myForm.end.oninput=()=>
  {
  let d_start = (new Date(myForm.start.value)) || Infinity
    , d_end   = (new Date(myForm.end.value)) || 0

  myForm.btSubmit.disabled =( d_start > d_end)
  }
```